# Updating git repo with submodules to latest commit on origin

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to update git repo with submodules to latest commit on origin with one command?

I'm aware of `git submodule update –remote` but I would like to update main repo as well so all be synced together, does git has such command?

Comment: Does the latest version of your repo also use the latest version of your submodule?

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: if you often need to do that task, write a script?

Comment: agree, tought it would be more common operation to update main repo and its submodules, I guess somethink like `git pull && git submodule update –remote` shouold work here